# Not working with django-nested-admin

Tags: django, admin, inlines

When I try add new inline in django-nested-admin, counter js not working.

[image]

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Thank you all, I found a solution to make ckeditor with django-nested-admin, problem is ckeditor js, some rewrite script js, and nested inline js